# Problem while uploading to a server a bot coded in discord.py

Tags: python, server, discord, bots, discord.py

first time here, I've recently made a little discord Bot that helps the teachers to make calling in discord class.

The Bot is working as long as I'm uploading it on my own computer, but it is costing me lot to keep my computer on during all day. So I've recently paid a server on cursehosting.com and have uploaded my bot, but there, nothing seems to work...

here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions,has_role
import logging
from asyncio import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from os import remove

#[==== Affichage des logs
logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
#====]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')#initialisation du prefix de commande pour le bot
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    """fonction affichant un message au démarrage du bot"""
    print('Bot est démarré.\n')
    
@client.command()
#@has_permissions(administrator=True) #commande exclusive aux enseignants/admins
@has_role("Enseignant")
async def appel(ctx, *, cours = "Cours Non Définit"):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Faire l'appel"))
    nom_fichier = "Fiche-Appel-"+cours+"-"+ctx.author.name+".txt"#nom du fichier de l'appel
    
    msg = await ctx.send(f"Le cours __ {cours} __ commence!\n> Merci de signaler votre présence en **cliquant sur le ✅ \
**en réaction de ce message d'ici à 15 minutes :alarm_clock:.\n||Pour que votre présence soit validée, il faut que votre pseudonyme\
 soit votre nom + prénom.||")
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")
    await sleep(900) #=== Valeur à changer, temps (en secondes) durant lequel les élèves peuvent se manifester.

    users = set()
    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(client.cached_messages, id=msg.id)
    for reaction in cache_msg.reactions:
        async for user in reaction.users():
            users.add(user)
    with open(nom_fichier, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(datetime.now()))
        file.write("\nFiche d'appel du cours {}, par {}\n\nEtudiant(e)s présent(e)s:\n".format(cours, ctx.author.name))
        for user in users:
            if user.bot == True: #ne pas register la réaction de BOT
                continue
            if user.nick != None: 
                file.write(str(user.nick)+" \n")
            else: #si l'utilisateur n'a pas de pseudonyme local
                file.write(str(user.name)+" \n")
    with open(nom_fichier, "rb") as file:
        channel = client.get_channel(756267947080548563)
        await channel.send("Fiche d'appel du cours {}, par {}".format(cours, ctx.author.name), file=discord.File(file, nom_fichier))
    try:
        remove(nom_fichier)
    except:
        print("Aucun fichier n'a été trouvé pour la suppression automatique\nfichier recherché : {}".format(nom_fichier))
@appel.error
async def appel_error(error, ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Vous n'avez pas les permissions requises pour faire l'appel")
client.run('token')
```

**Here is the requirements I've installed on my server:
discord.py / asyncio / datetime
And here is the error I get:**

> Ignoring exception in command appel
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 50, in wrapped
> ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "main.py", line 29, in appel
> nom_fichier = "Fiche-Appel-"+cours+"-"+ctx.author.name+".txt"#nom du fichier de l'appel
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 846, in process_commands
> yield from command.invoke(ctx)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 374, in invoke
> yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 54, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

I don't know what else I could give... Working on Python3.6

Comment: Have you made sure you are using the same version of Python and all packages on your hosting as you have on your personal machine?

Comment: Just as a tip: Don't give out your bot Token.  It allows anyone who has it run code as your bot on any of their servers.  I'd reset your token and remove that one from your code.

Comment: hey thanks for the tip lol completly forgot about the token